# Does "to wise" make sense in English?

Tags: grammar

We had a discussion with our collegues about this.

They think "to wise" means something like "the way to wisdom" but I really can't put it in my brain since it sounds off to me. I proposed that the closest one would be "to wisdom" but since we're not native English speakers, we can't be sure.

Is "to wise" appropriate to use in English?

Example sentence:
For a rookie, road to wise is long and exhausting.

Comment: Are your colleagues trying to use 'wise' as a verb? We need an example of how they want to use it in a sentence.

Comment: They are using it as "to have virtue". Even if they are using for some other meaning, does it sound ok?

Comment: I've never heard the phrase *to wise*. I have, however, heard the phrase *to wit*. (Which means "in other words" or "that is to say.") Are they confusing the two?

Comment: You still haven't given an example sentence, but, no, it doesn't sound OK.

Comment: @KateBunting added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to shorten “in the direction of X” to “to X”, X needs to be a noun. It can be an abstract noun such as *wisdom* or *folly*, but not an adjective like “wise”.

The rationale is that even a metaphorical movement towards something requires a ‘thing’ to move towards, rather than merely an attribute of one.

Now, sometimes [adjectives can be used as nouns](https://www.englishgrammar.org/adjectives-nouns-2/). To the extent that is possible, you *can* use the noun form or noun ‘sense’ with “to” as a direction.

For example, *they are the wise* uses “the wise” as a noun phrase denoting a group of people (not merely a personification of wisdom), so you can move towards them: “go to the wise”. Here, the natural sense would also be to go to the specified group of people, rather than metaphorically towards wisdom.

Returning to your question: the word “wise” on its own doesn’t seem to be able to be treated as a noun, so * *to wise* wouldn’t be “appropriate to use in English”.

Comment: Do you think there is another place to use "to wise" in any other sentence? Or maybe it does have a meaning alone?

Comment: You can say “to *wise up*”, but that uses “wise up” rather than just “wise” on its own. You might also be able to get away with it in poetry.

Comment: @RamazanPolat Word-play is another possibility: *the wise and fall of seasonal dieting* (that example doesn’t use *to*, but similar constraints would normally apply).

Answer (score 1):

The *Oxford English Dictionary*, the verb "wise" is marked

> Obsolete exc. Sc. and northern dialect.

So if you are in Scotland or northern England you may hear this.